# Running OSGI Bundle Projects

Tags: eclipse, osgi, bundle, osgi-bundle, activator

I am working on the Eclipse IDE and am trying to run osgi bundle projects. I have created 2 bundles using plugin projects.

1. CalculatorService (Which acts as the Publisher)
2. CalculatorClient (Which acts as the subscriber)

This is my project structure

[image: project structure]

When I try to run `CalculatorService` it executes fine and the service is active. Then once the `CalculatorService` is `ACTIVE`, I run the `CalculatorClient`. But it stays in the `RESOLVED` status and is not `ACTIVE`.

[image: Service status]

In-spite of not being able to get the CalculatorClient Bundle `ACTIVE`, I tried starting that service and got a gogo exception as follows.

[image: gogo exception]

Since this exception says that there is something erraneous with my `start()` method of the `CalculatorClient` bundle, I have attached it herewith.

```
package calculatorclient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceReference;

import calculatorservice.ICalculatorService;

public class CalculatorClient implements BundleActivator {

    ServiceReference servRef;
    private static BundleContext context;

    static BundleContext getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator#start(org.osgi.framework.BundleContext)
     */
    public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
        CalculatorClient.context = bundleContext;
        System.out.println("Start calculate client service");
        servRef = context.getServiceReference(ICalculatorService.class.getName());
        ICalculatorService calc = (ICalculatorService)context.getService(servRef);

        //Print
        System.out.println("Enter Operator");
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String oper = br1.readLine();
        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        double no1 = Double.parseDouble(br2.readLine());
        BufferedReader br3 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        double no2 = Double.parseDouble(br3.readLine());

        System.out.print("Answer is ");
        calc.calculateService(oper, no1, no2);

    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator#stop(org.osgi.framework.BundleContext)
     */
    public void stop(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
        CalculatorClient.context = null;
        System.out.println("Good Bye !!!");
        context.ungetService(servRef);
    }

}
```

**The activator class of the CalculatorService bundle**

```
package calculatorservice;

import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceRegistration;

public class CalculatorActivator implements BundleActivator {

    ServiceRegistration servReg;
    private static BundleContext context;

    static BundleContext getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator#start(org.osgi.framework.BundleContext)
     */
    public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
        CalculatorActivator.context = bundleContext;
        ICalculatorService calc = new CalculatorServiceImpl();
        servReg = context.registerService(ICalculatorService.class.getName(), calc, null);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator#stop(org.osgi.framework.BundleContext)
     */
    public void stop(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
        CalculatorActivator.context = null;
        servReg.unregister();
    }

}
```

**CalculatorService MANIFEST.MF**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: CalculatorService
Bundle-SymbolicName: CalculatorService
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: calculatorservice.CalculatorActivator
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0"
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Export-Package: calculatorservice
```

**CalculatorClient MANIFEST.MF**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: CalculatorClient
Bundle-SymbolicName: CalculatorClient
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: calculatorclient.CalculatorClient
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Import-Package: calculatorservice, org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0"
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
```

**Stacktrace**

```
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver [1674]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.m2e.jdt; bundle-version="[1.0.0,2.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.m2e.jdt; bundle-version="1.6.2.20150902-0002"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.m2e.jdt [1376]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.m2e.core; bundle-version="[1.6.0,1.7.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.m2e.core; bundle-version="1.6.2.20150902-0002"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.m2e.core [1371]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.m2e.workspace.cli; bundle-version="0.1.0"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1562)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

Any suggestions on why I am unable to get this CalculatorClient bundle go from the `RESOLVED` state to an `ACTIVE` state will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you are using Equinox, have a look in the configuration folder of your OSGi container. Equinox puts the error messages into some uniquely named files in the configuration folder if not specified otherwise. As you cannot know in which order your bundles are starting, you should never use context.getService() in your start method of an Activator as the other bundle might not have been started yet.

Comment: @BalazsZsoldos . In my project, I am initially starting the CalculatorService bundle by right clicking on that bundle's `MANIFEST.MF` and then select `Run as` -> `OSGI Framework`. And once the `CalculatorService bundle is `ACTIVE` I do the same on the `MANIFEST.MF` of the `CalculatorClient` bundle. So in this case won't the bundle's be started individually in the same order I run them regardless of the `context.getService()?

Comment: Well, there is an exception somewhere in your start method, but I do not know where its stacktrace is written to. Therefore I can only suggest the ugly solution that you should wrap your entiry body of the start method with a try-catch, and call an e.printstacktrace in the catch. You will at least see the real exception.

Comment: @BalazsZsoldos I did print the stacktrace and I've added to my question. Could you please suggest something based on this. I'm pretty new to osgi bundles.

Comment: I hardly think that that is the stacktrace that comes out from your start method. It is an exception but it is independent from your current issue. There might be a NumberFormatException on Double.parseDouble function call. That is my first guess, but seeing the exception with stacktrace instead of guessing would be better. Please note, that in real systems you should not block in the start method of the bundle (e.g.: waiting for some user input) as it blocks the startup of the whol computer.

Answer (score 0):

I made a few minor modification to both of my Activator classes.

- Rather than using the bundle context instance declared out of the `start()` and `stop()` methods, I used to bundlecontext object parameter within the `start()` and `stop()` methods.
- Add an `@Override` annotation right before both the `start()` and `stop()` methods.
- Add an `@Override` annotation right before the method declaration in the class that implements the interface within the publisher bundle.
- Remove any unnecessary default declarations created by during project initialization from the Activator classes.

**Publisher's Activator Class**

```
package calculatorservice;

import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceRegistration;

public class CalculatorActivator implements BundleActivator {

    ServiceRegistration serviceRegistration;

    @Override
    public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
        ICalculatorService iCalculatorService = new CalculatorServiceImpl();
        serviceRegistration = bundleContext.registerService(ICalculatorService.class.getName(), iCalculatorService, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
        serviceRegistration.unregister();
    }

}
```

**Publisher's Implementation Class**

```
package calculatorservice;

public class CalculatorServiceImpl implements ICalculatorService{
    @Override
    public void calculateService(String operator, double no1, double no2){
        String PLUS = "+";
        String MINUS = "-";
        String MUL = "*";
        String DIV = "/";
        if(PLUS.equals(operator))
        {
            System.out.print((no1+no2));
        }
        else if (MINUS.equals(operator)){
            System.out.println((no1-no2));
        }
        else if (MUL.equals(operator)){
            System.out.print((no1*no2));
        }
        else if(DIV.equals(operator)){
            if(no2 == 0.0){
                System.out.print(" \"Divide by zeo error \" ");
            }
            else{
                System.out.print((no1/no2));
            }
        }
        else if (operator == ""){
            System.out.print(" \"Enter value for operator\" ");
        }
        else{
            System.out.print(" \"Enter one of the operators +_*/ \" ");
        }
    }
}
```

**Client's Activator Class**

```
package calculatorclient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceReference;

import calculatorservice.ICalculatorService;

public class CalculatorClient implements BundleActivator {

    ServiceReference serviceReference;

    @Override
    public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Start calculate client Service");
        serviceReference = bundleContext.getServiceReference(ICalculatorService.class.getName());
        ICalculatorService iCalculatorService = (ICalculatorService)bundleContext.getService(serviceReference);

        System.out.println("Enter operator");
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String operator = br1.readLine();

        System.out.println("Enter no1 = ");
        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        double no1 = Double.parseDouble(br2.readLine());

        System.out.println("Enter no2 = ");
        BufferedReader br3 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        double no2 = Double.parseDouble(br3.readLine());

        iCalculatorService.calculateService(operator,no1,no2);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Good Bye!!!");
        bundleContext.ungetService(serviceReference);       
    }

}
```

And then I started the Publisher's `MANIFEST.MF` separately. Once that was `ACTIVE`, I started the Client's `MANIFEST.MF`. Once both of these were `ACTIVE` Start the Client service and the program will run fine.